# trouble setting default alt tag of enlarged product images

Tags: product-attribute, product-images, seo, product-tag

I have been trying to figure out which layer/.phtml/extension is responsible for the empty `alt=""` in the enlarged images on a site, for example at

https://www.seart.pl/wieszak-polka-vintage-vpk-p-5619.html

The idea is to default to a product or category name when an label is empty.
Being somewhat new, I have poured through [guides](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/1555-yireo-guidelines-for-magento-modification) and followed changes in code from [related examples](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74623/magento-product-image-name-seo-dynamically), to no avail. Even after I manually refresh some caches (is that necessary?) and rebuild indexes, an F12 element inspection of the resulting HTML in the browser shows a blank *alt=* value, which affects web crawlers.

https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO had been installed, but does not enforce

`Make "alt" tags mandatory on product gallery images?`

(only temporarily  as in this screenshot)

[image: temporarily enforced alt tags]

What other files, templates, extensions or settings should I look into?

These two *didn't* help:

- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml

Answer (score 1):

The reason your not finding the template responsible is because there is no template file responsible for this. It's a piece of javascript. I took this snippet from your site:

```
<img src="https://www.seart.pl/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/480x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/s/z/szafa_dwudrzwiowa_sosnowa_1.jpg" data-zoom-image="https://www.seart.pl/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/960x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/s/z/szafa_dwudrzwiowa_sosnowa_1.jpg" alt="Szafa sosnowa Vintage" title="Szafa sosnowa Vintage" class="main-zoom-img" style="position: absolute;">
```

If you look closely, the image in the `src=` tag has a size of 480. (the numbers after the /cache/1/thumbnail part). Then the `data-zoom-image=` part, contains the larger version of this image. When this element is being clicked, the html is being modified into this fancybox showing you the larger image. You can see this happening if you focus at the html.

The only reason i can think of why this alt tag shouldn't be blank, is SEO purposes. But to my recollection, search engines aren't doing this kind of interaction. They will never see this empty image alt tag because it's not there on page load. And i'm not sure, but i think the bigger version of this image isn't even indexed. Maybe someone can fill me up on this one.

However, it is possible to get something like the product name in this alt tag when it's clicked. You can load complete HTML fragments in fancyboxes like these. I once used it to create an AJAX login window. I think this version is being used at your site.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs